# Confusion around ERC1155 nft ownership

Tags: nft, erc-1155

I came across an ERC1155 nft token which is at the same time owned by two wallet addresses. I asked a friend how is that possible and they told me that ERC1155 tokens can be owned by multiple accounts at the same time and it is kind of like a partial ownership.

1. Is this correct?
2. Let's say this NFT is in both wallet A and B. What happens if wallet A transfers it to wallet B? Because the wallet B already has this token.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Correct - the smart contract can be built so people can own fractions of a token, that token is then represented as a % of the specified NFT ID.
2. If the contract is built correctly - the transaction simply won't execute, you can try submitting the tx and will probably be charged a huge amount of gas but because the function to have duplicate IDs under one address doesn't exist it's in violation of the code so it just fails. See examples - as you can see there are numerous considerations to the logic here.

```
    function depositAsset() public {
        require(!deposited, "NFT already deposited");
        msg.sender.transfer(address(this).balance);
        asset.transferFrom(msg.sender, address(this), assetId);
        deposited = true;
    }
```

```
    modifier isTransferable(address _from, address _to) {
        require(asset.ownerOf(assetId) == address(this), "asset not owned");
        require(!approved[_from], "transfer from account that approved the sale");
        require(!approved[_to], "transfer to account that approved the sale");
        require(!sold, "asset already sold"); // can we allow token transfer after the sale?
        _;
    }
```